# How do I use the --step-size option in the crepe module?

Tags: python, audio

I am using crepe for a Python project. The documentation for the module mentions that there is a `--step-size` command that will allow you to change how frequently the module analyzes pitch.

Comment: you can use it in console/terminal/bash/cmd.exe `crepe --step-size 30 audio_file.wav` or `python -m crepe --step-size 30 audio_file.wav`. You can't use it directly in your script. You would have to check in documentation if some function use similar argument. Or you would have to get `creape` source code and see how it uses value from `--step-size`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it in `console`/`terminal`/`bash`/`cmd.exe`

```
crepe --step-size 30 audio_file.wav
```

or

```
python -m crepe --step-size 30 audio_file.wav
```

You can't use it directly in your script. You would have to check in documentation if some functions use similar argument.

Or you would have to get crepe source code and see how it uses value from `--step-size`.

---

**EDIT:**

Digging in [source code](https://github.com/marl/crepe/blob/master/crepe/core.py) I see:

```
get_activation( ..., step_size=10)

predict( ..., step_size=10)

process_file( ..., step_size=10)
```

So it seems you can use this value in all these functions.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.